# AlivePdf create a map chart

Tags: actionscript, alivepdf

I'm building a pure actionscript project and would like to create a pdf with an map chart of the world to display my data.

It's possible to create a map and save as image and then embed in pdf with alivepdf?

```
package
{
    import MyButton;

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.external.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import org.alivepdf.display.*;
    import org.alivepdf.fonts.*;
    import org.alivepdf.layout.*;
    import org.alivepdf.pdf.*;
    import org.alivepdf.saving.*;

    public class WorldTest extends Sprite
    {

        private var saveButton:MyButton = new MyButton();
        // declared of logo or imagen on top of the PDF's document.
        [Embed(source="FCMap_World.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream" )]
        protected var jpgBytes:Class;
        protected var pdf:PDF;

        public function WorldTest() {
            saveButton.y = 0;
            addChild(saveButton);

            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClickEvent);
        }

        protected function onMouseClickEvent(event:Event):void{
            pdf = new PDF(Orientation.LANDSCAPE, Unit.MM, Size.LETTER);
            pdf.setDisplayMode(Display.FULL_WIDTH);
            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(new jpgBytes() as DisplayObject, null, 0, 0, 0);

            var bytes:ByteArray = pdf.save(Method.LOCAL);
            var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
            file.save(bytes, "myPDF.pdf");


        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to add swf file as image. 
You need to make an image from it first.

```
   var map : MovieClip = new jpgBytes();
   var bitmapData : BitmapData = new BitmapData(map.width, map.height);
   bitmapData.draw(map);
   var bitmap : Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
```

You can try to use another library called [PDFcase](https://github.com/dickclaus/pdfcase) for creating pdf in ActionScript.

[This example](https://github.com/dickclaus/pdfcase/blob/master/test-src/org/asusual/pdfcase/test/Example03.as) shows how to add images to pdf.

Comment: Is there a documentation or tutorial using PDFcase?